# Date in darwin standard library giving me the wrong date?

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, standard-library, darwin

What is wrong with this code in swift accessing the time and date functions in C? The date it gives me is off by 3 days even though the difftime function is correct on the time difference.

```
 import Darwin
    var time1 = tm(tm_sec: 00, tm_min: 00, tm_hour: 00, tm_mday: 13, tm_mon: 06, tm_year: 1977, tm_wday: 0, tm_yday: 0, tm_isdst: 0, tm_gmtoff: 0, tm_zone: nil)
    var time1secs = timegm(&time1)
    var time2secs = timegm(&time1) + 1_000_000_000
    var time2 = gmtime(&time2secs).memory

    difftime(time2secs, time1secs) // 1,000,000,000
    print("\(time2.tm_year)-\(time2.tm_mon)-\(time2.tm_mday)") //2009-2-22

    // The correct answer is 2009-02-19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `struct tm`, the `tm_year` field is the number of years
since 1900, and `tm_mon` is the month in the range 0 .. 11:

```
// struct tm for 1977/06/13:
var time1 = tm()
time1.tm_year = 1977 - 1900
time1.tm_mon = 06 - 1
time1.tm_mday = 13

// Add 10^9 seconds:
var time2secs = timegm(&time1) + 1_000_000_000
var time2 = gmtime(&time2secs).memory

// Extract year/month/day:
let year = time2.tm_year + 1900
let month = time2.tm_mon + 1
let day = time2.tm_mday
print("\(year)-\(month)-\(day)") // 2009-2-19
```

Comment: Thank you. I made these an extension to tm in this gist. https://gist.github.com/masters3d/b90a99aac6b923add0ee

Comment: @masters3d: Good idea! I would probably use `Int` for the public properties because that is more common in Swift, but that may be a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks for all the help with this API. I wish swift comes out with a native Date type when is open sourced.